# Wordpress plugin - using backbone.js

Tags: php, backbone.js, wordpress

I want to create a custom wordpress plugin. I want to use backbone.js. I have used backbone for non php/wordpress related projects. Can someone guide me to how to go about writing the plugin to make use of the mvc client side architecture? Thanks!

Comment: I would be very grateful if somebody could give me some sort of direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pushed WordpressSinglePage, a starting place for building single-page JavaScript applications on top of Backbone.js via Brunch (Backbone.js, CoffeeScript, EcoTemplates, jQuery --http://brunch.io/) and the Wordpress JSON api.  This should get you on the right track.

Updated link:
https://github.com/damassi/WordpressSinglePage-JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

My belief is that since backbone.js is a client side framework the bulk of the complexity is going to be in writing the actual plugin. Smashing Magazine has a great article "[WordPress Essentials: How To Create A WordPress Plugin](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/)" that should serve as a good starting point. Outside of that I would look at the discussions about "[Backbone.js How to use with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208473/981)" here on StackOverflow.

"If you're doing #PHP and need a RESTful API (for #BackboneJS, etc) the #[SlimPHP](http://www.slimframework.com/) framework looks pretty slick. It's like #Sinatra for PHP." [Derik Bailey](https://twitter.com/#!/derickbailey/status/161913316720115712)

Comment: thanks a lot dude. I used backbone that runs from model served by a wordpress plugin. I will use #SlimPHP to serve me the model.

Comment: you may want to take a look a this colorLabs project http://www.wpmods.com/backbone-wordpress-theme-framework/