# save in server by model or by collection?

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js

I'm confused about send collection or model to the server.

This is my model:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {},
    initialize : function() {}
});
```

and this is my collection:

```
var Usercollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Person,
    url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/'
});
```

Now, if I would save a model on the server I have first to add in a collection and use save on model or first add in a collection and use save on collection? And least, I have to write an ajax call to post the collection or model in a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the model to the collection after the model is saved, you need to use `.create` on the collection , which fires the **add event** on the collection after it gets created..

```
this.collection.create(model.toJSON() , options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save your model to server.

**Save a model**: Call `save()` on model e.g.

```
    var user = new UserModel();    
    user.save({name: 'SJ', age:'35'}, {
      success: function (user) {
        // I get a model here with id
      }
    });
```

Read these links for more information.

- [How to save your model data: SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816274/ways-to-save-backbone-js-model-data)
- [Sample code - by Thomas Davis in his screencast @ backbonetutorials.com - Must watch](https://github.com/blunderboy/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/videos/beginner/index.html)
- [Server side code for wine cellar app](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/)

I have given you the link of server side code to have a look at the APIs to make things more meaningful to you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point: If you look at code written by Thomas, you will get it. Whenever we save a model to backend, either you can add the model to collection in the success handler or you should fetch the complete collection. So when you make a call to fetch the entire collection, it will read you Database and make a list of models and return the list.

Comment: In thomas's code, in success handler of user.save() he redirects to a new route and in that very route he fetches entire collection from server and renders again. So the newly added model gets added to collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use collection.create();

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create

> Convenience to create a new instance of a model within a collection.
>   Equivalent to instantiating a model with a hash of attributes, saving
>   the model to the server, and adding the model to the set after being
>   successfully created. Returns the new model. ...

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});

var nypl = new Library;

var othello = nypl.create({
  title: "Othello",
  author: "William Shakespeare"
});
```