# backbone success event not called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Code

```
MyClass = Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: '/apiurl/'+sessionValue+'',
                defaults: {
                    data1: '',
                    data2: 1
                }
            });


            var myobj = new MyClass ();
            var myobjvalue = {  
            data1: "myvalue"
            };

            myobj.save(myobjvalue , {
                success: function (myobj , response) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error : function (myobj , response) {
                           var data = JSON.stringify(response);
                                       console.log(data);
                                    }
            })
```

in the above code, save function successfully calls the REST api. (200 OK). However even after that it enters in error block.

value printed in console
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"Success","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

What should I be doing?

===================================

What worked

Instead of string, I had to return actual object as part of REST API. apprently, backbone expects class object along with HTTP status. so responseText contained full myobj.

Comment: is the reply a valid json object ?

Comment: Just because you got a 200 response doesn't necessarily mean there wasn't an error...

Comment: Show us how it looks the response obj

Comment: added response object

Comment: What is the "Content-Type" returned by the server?

Comment: What exactly is your server returning? Just the string `"Success"`?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816274/ways-to-save-backbone-js-model-data

Comment: mu : yes.. @NicolaeOlariu : will read.

Comment: Nopes, still not able to make it work

Comment: done. instead of string, I had to return actual object as part of REST API. apprently, backbone expects class object along with HTTP status

Answer (score 0):

What worked

Instead of string, I had to return actual object as part of REST API. apprently, backbone expects class object along with HTTP status. so responseText contained full myobj.