# How to update and send backbone model to express backend

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I want to update a backbone model so that I can set the data of a backbone model and then update it on the express backend but so far I have not been successful. I have checked the urls on the routes and it is correct but so far it has not been sent to the backend.

Here is the update part of the code.

```
update: function() {
    this.$('#noteParent .note-editable').prop('contenteditable', false);
    this.$('#aboutParent .note-editable').prop('contenteditable', false);
    this.$('#update').prop('disabled', true);
    var notes = this.$('#noteParent .note-editable').html();
    var about = this.$('#aboutParent .note-editable').html();
    var username = $('#data-username').text();
    app.url = "/update-usernotes";
    this.model.set({
        username: username,
        email: app.email,
        about: about,
        editorNote: notes
    });
}
```

Is the set method the right method to update the model ? Also on doing console.log(this.model) right before this.model.set i get the updated model, so how can I send the updates to the backend ?

Comment: can you be more specific , do you want to send PUT request or just make a request to backend?

Comment: I want to update the data on the backend

Comment: just let me know how do you want to update the data at backend? , by sending what type of request(like POST or PUT)?

Comment: You answer worked, i used a POST request

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to save Backbone.js model data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816274/ways-to-save-backbone-js-model-data)

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin In a way it is in a way it is not a duplicate since my question has to do with updating the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set make changes locally to model , when you want to make a request to to backend use `save`

```
 this.model.save({                        
                        username: username,
                        email: app.email,
                        about: about,
                        editorNote: notes   
                },{})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought, that i had to use the set method

Answer (score 0):

use this.model.save for database operations
for more 
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save