# simple PHP code sample to serve backbone.js

Tags: php, backbone.js

Experience level: newbie.

The [backbone.js Todos demo](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) uses localStorage. This question is about how to use PHP to serve the page instead, assuming that a MySQL DB has been set up.

I checked out PHP frameworks such as CodeIgniter but found them difficult to follow and possibly overkill for my learning purposes.

I understand the concept that a REST API needs to be set up. I am really looking for simple code samples. Thanks in advance.

Update: Is there a full backbone.js tutorial somewhere that includes a full working example of how to wire up to server side PHP?

Comment: If you've never done any PHP you might want to look at using `node.js` and [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) to expose a REST api for you. You can also just set up a couch database which automatically exposes a REST api for data access instead of mySQL.

Comment: Thanks Raynos for the suggestion I'll look into it. Without getting into details of my situation and for the purposes of this question, the assumption is that there is a specific requirement that PHP be used.

Comment: You can look this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755074/a-restful-persistence-solution-usable-with-backbone-js-in-php/5965699#5965699

Comment: Thanks I did before already, it points to a few different frameworks such as CI but I find them difficult to follow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most basic and simple approach (I know of) that should help you to get started, would be:

1. Given you have a model / collection, define it with an url like:

   resourceCollection: Backbone.Collection.extend({
         **url: '/page.php'**
       })
2. Create your **page.php** file (in the document root),  just take care of RewriteRules etc. you may use!
3. Now we have to make sure that we can react properly on get, put, post and delete; so we have to check for the request method, e.g. with a switch statement. Cases would be GET, DELETE, PUT, POST:

   switch(**$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']**){
      ...
   }

Answer (score 4):

The following should give you an idea (php controllers are implemented using Silex framework + Paris library for the data access):

```
// GET  /{resource}/{id}    Show
$app->get('/api/todos/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->find_one($id);

    return new Response(json_encode($todo->as_array()), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
});

// POST     /{resource}     Create
$app->post('/api/todos', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->create();
    $todo->title = $data->title;
    $todo->save();

    return new Response(json_encode($todo->as_array()), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
});

// PUT  /{resource}/{id}    Update
$app->put('/api/todos/{id}', function ($id, Request $request) use ($app) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->find_one($id);
    $todo->title = $data->title;
    $todo->save();

    return new Response('Todo updated', 200);
});

// DELETE   /{resource}/{id}    Destroy
$app->delete('/api/todos/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $todo =  $app['paris']->getModel('Todo')->find_one($id);
    $todo->delete(); 

    return new Response('Todo deleted', 200);
});
```

To get your backbone collection working with the above interface, all you have to do is to set the url property like:

```
window.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,

    url: "api/todos",

    ...
});
```

Recently, I have written a tutorial on how to do GET/POST/PUT/DELETE with Backbone.js and PHP http://cambridgesoftware.co.uk/blog/item/59-backbonejs-%20-php-with-silex-microframework-%20-mysql, might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The example:
https://github.com/ccoenraets/wine-cellar-php

... from this article:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/

... is good because it encapsulates a configured PHP RESTful server (Slim). From the perspective of working with backbone.js, this seems to essentially be the entirety of what you need on the server side - simply a RESTful service!

For my basic web config (am not good with rewrite rules), I had to modify the file ../final/js/models/winemodel.js (where I add ***index.php***) as follows:

```
url:"../api/index.php/wines"
```