# Syncing Backbone/Spine application to a database

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, backbone.js, crud

I have just about got my head around how JavaScript frameworks like Backbone.js and Spine.js deals with the client-side state of a data model in regards to updating views etc. I am looking to build a web application with Backbone that syncs its model with a database. Most of the examples out there use Ruby, but I am currently much more comfortable writing PHP. I have experience with MySQL and MongoDB.

I am looking for a very basic, stripped down version, of a RESTful web application that uses Backbone and syncs with a database through PHP. I have found tutorials like [this one](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) and [this one](http://cambridgesoftware.co.uk/blog/item/59-backbonejs-%20-php-with-silex-microframework-%20-mysql/), however, even these are too complex for me to learn from.

It would be nice to have a *very* basic example. For example, a HTML form input, and a list. Enter into the input to add to the list. Of course, this data model will be synced to a database (preferably MySQL). Would anyone be able to provide me with the code for this example? I am comfortable with using a PHP framework like Slim also.

Once I understand how to sync created data to a database, I can then begin to grasp the rest (CRUD). I have seen very few tutorials out there on how to this at a basic level with PHP, so hopefully any support will benefit others too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this one [from net.tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/)? I think they will post a new tut soon with more details

**Edit**

And there are at least 2 similar questions here actually:

- [simple PHP code sample to serve backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283100/simple-php-code-sample-to-serve-backbone-js)
- [Backbone.js How to use with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207286/backbone-js-how-to-use-with-php)

Comment: I have indeed. I understand Backbone, it's just using it with a back-end solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I have looked at both of those. I understand the logic to it, but I need an example. The Todo example is overkill for my learning purposes. I just want a very basic example to help me understand at the moment.