# MySQL to JSON via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Let me preface this with I know this question has been asked plenty of times on here (ie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445495/mysql-to-json-in-php) among other pages) and I've trawled through each of the answers and tried the solutions but keep getting an empty json array.

I've got a mysql query as per below:

```
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT player_name, player_team, 
SUM(ruckContests) AS contests FROM afl_master 
WHERE player_team = "COLL" AND year = 2019 AND ruckContests > 0 
GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY contests DESC LIMIT 2');
```

The output to this query is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [player_name] => Brodie Grundy [player_team] => COLL [contests] => 661 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [player_name] => Mason Cox [player_team] => COLL [contests] => 51 ) )
```

What I want to do is convert this to the following json object in php:

```
{
 player_name: "Brodie Grundy", 
 player_team: "COLL", 
 contests: 661
},
{
 player_name: "Mason Cox", 
 player_team: "COLL", 
 contests: 51
}
```

I've tried `mysql_fetch_array()` as well as `fetch_assoc()` using the method [here](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/php/100/mysql-to-json.html) but to no avail. I'd appreciate any help available.

---

This simple solution recommended in the comments worked:

```
json_encode($myQuery)
```

Comment: Try `json_encode($myQuery)`

Comment: Oh my god, it was that simple. I was trying to pre-process it then use json_encode(). Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$JsonData=array();
foreach($myQuery as $val){


            $JsonData[]='
               {
                 "player_name": "'.$val->player_name.'", 
                 "player_team": "'.$val->player_team.'", 
                 "contests": $val->contests 
               }
             ';
}
$expectedJson=implode(',',$JsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast your result to array with *fetch_array()* or (array) $myQuery then:

```
json_encode($myQuery);
json_last_error(); // to see the error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in single SQL Statement (I have just formatted it in multiple lines for better understanding). The inner Select statement uses your query as a sub-query, while using  [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to generate JSON object of each row, finally using GROUP_CONCAT to combine each row with a comma, and then add the "[" and "]" to the final result for creating a perfect JSON array.  (Just another way, apart from the *json_encode($myQuery)*, the simpler version *:)*  ).

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT( 
        JSON_OBJECT( 
            'player_name',   player_name, 
            'player_team' ,  player_team, 
            'contests', contests) 
    ) , ']') as json  
FROM (
        SELECT  player_name,  player_team, SUM(ruckContests) as contests
        FROM afl_master 
        WHERE player_team = "COLL" AND year = 1995 AND ruckContests > 0 
        GROUP BY player_name, player_team 
        ORDER BY SUM(ruckContests) DESC 
        LIMIT 2 
) AS TT
```